# Binomial Distribution Question... Beer Tasting Probability getting 7 or more correct

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, solution-verification

In order to select its beer tasters, a brewey give an applicant a tasting examination.   The applicant is presented with five glasses, one of which contains ale and four of which contain beer, and is asked to identify the one contain ale.

If the procedure is repeated 10 times and the brewery requries 7 or more correct answers for a satisfactory socre, what is the probability that an applicant will pass the test if he cannot discriminate and only guesses each time?

I think this is a binomial distribution so I have set-up $b(7;10, \frac1 5)$= ${10 \choose 7}(\frac 1 5)^7(\frac4 5)^3$.

However, I am now beginning to doubt that this is the probability the person gets 7 or more.  I think this is the probability of 7... So do I need to take P(7)+P(8)+P(9)+P(10)?

Comment: Yes, you need to add up the 4 cases.

Comment: You are correct. If $X$ represents the number of questions correctly answered, taking the summation of each of the cases as you specified will represent $P(X \geq 7)$, whereas currently you only have $P(X = 7)$. A pass is evidently not just getting 7 questions right ($P(X = 7)$, it is getting 7 _or more_ right $P(X \geq 7)$.

Comment: Alternatively you can compute $1-P(x\le6)$ using the cumulative binomial distribution $normacdf$ on the TI-84 family calculators